# pythonでスマホのアプリは作れますか？

Tags: python

最近から機械学習などをpythonで勉強し始めたプログラミング初心者です。
ふと思ったのですがpythonでスマホのアプリなどは作れますか。
それとも他に作りやすい言語がありますか。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

できますが、ネイティブコンポネンツ（ボタンやラベルなど）を使えなくて、OpenGLになります。もしゲームなど、カスタムな見た目求めているアプリを作っているなら、これはむしろいいことかもしれません。

他にもあるかもしれないが、知っているのはこれです。
https://kivy.org/